# During install, get window with following error message "Can't open var/log/partition_dump"

Tags: system-installation

New to Linux, and I'm installing Ubuntu for desktop, version 22.04.3 LTS. The installation was working until I got to the "Where are you?" step. A window comes up with ERROR! Can't open `/var/log/partition_dump` with an OK button.
Hitting the OK button does nothing, I'm able to open the upper right-hand window with the power off option but will not let me power off/log out.
This is a secondary computer that I'm testing Linux.  How do I get past this?  Manually power down and would that mess up the installation?
This was an install directly on the drive vs the try it option.

Comment: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=380127 says to wipe the drive then retry the installation

Comment: Wiping the drive worked.  However, it took a bit to figure out how to wipe the drive.  The computer was an HP with Windows 10.  Apparently the BIOS  on consumer machines does not include the Secure Erase function.  Decided to try the Windows "Reset this PC" function and that worked.